# SVN repository has changes, but 'svn up' does not apply these to our filesystem

Tags: svn, aptana

I'll start by saying that we're new to Subversion, so we're not 100% on the processes and terminology, but it seems something is not working as it should so we're looking for help.

We're using Aptana with the Subversion plugin and we have connected to our Subversion 1.6.1 repository just fine.
We can make a change and sync and commit this change to our SVN server. We can see using websvn that it has correctly recorded the changes against a version number and shows which files are edited and our comments, so I think this is fine up to here.

When we then use SSH and we navigate to the file system directory and run 'svn update' it gives us a message to say 'at revision 53' for example. This revision number corresponds with the revision we've commited via Aptana and can see with the websvn.

But.... no files are changed on the server following this 'svn up' command :-(
Does anyone have any ideas please? It feels like we're missing something obvious, but can't work it out.
We've tried it with '--depth infinity' but no difference.
thanks in advance,

Comment: What does `svn stat` tell you on the server? If there are no updates waiting and no changed files on the server then its all working fine. Either you've not committed changes from the working copy (remember you have to `svn add file.txt` before you can `svn commit`) or you're imagining differences in files. :p Also don't use Subversion, use Git. I will impart my 6 months experience with SVN on you right now... you'll end up switching to Git in the end anyway.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, if I change specifically to the directory where I expect the file to change and run svn stat it tells me 'Status against revision:     53' but doesn't mention any files.
I'm pretty sure the files are committed correctly as that's part of the Aptana plugin's job and I can see via the websvn that the change is listed against the revision number

Answer (score 0):

First you check your updates you take the right path..It's happening some times.Try to Commit it again. or else you delete old folder and take fresh copy again

Comment: Thanks Chathura, I've just checked and it appears that our main development directory points to the development branch for it's url path in the svn info, but all subdirectories within point to the main trunk in the url path instead. I wonder how that has happened...
So it looks like the svn catalog is working, but the working directories are looking to the wrong place to get their new versions of the files

Answer (score 0):

There should be a "Clean up" function, use it and it should do the same as deleting and restoring if you dont have changes.